# Error attempting to install SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-xp

when i try to run the setup.exe to start the installation, i get the following error in windows_xp:

Microsoft .NET Framework CAS Policy Manager has encountered a problem and needs to close.

this is what is in the error signature:
AppName: caspol.exe      AppVer: 2.0.50727.3053     AppStamp:4889dd08
ModName: mscorwks.dll      ModVer: 2.0.50727.3607      ModStamp:4add5446
fDebug: 0       Offset: 000d0494

i have tried completely removing and reinstalling all of my .net installations and it didn't resolve the  issue. it's weird, because one time i tried to run setup i got two application events but subsequent tries did not produce more events.

the first event's id is 1023:

.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3607 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A09795E) (80131506)

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the uninstallation did not remove all objects such as registry keys.

This may be of some use but I cannot verify its success rate having not used it myself.

http://www.justanswer.com/computer/5gtob-microsoft-net-framework-cas-policy-manager-encountered.html